# Lacunary Fourier series and Hölder continuity at a point on the circle

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lacunary-series

Let $(\lambda_{n})$ be lacunary (i.e. $\exists$ constant $q>1$ such that $\lambda_{n+1}>q\lambda_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$); $f\in L^{1}(T)$ with Fourier series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_{n}\cos(\lambda_{n}t)$ and suppose also that $f$ is Hölder continuous at a point $t_{0}\in T$.

I want to show that $a_{n}=O(\lambda^{-\alpha}_{n})$ and also that $f$ is Hölder continuous on $T$.

Thus we have that $\hat{f}(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_{n}\cos(\lambda_{n}t)$ and that $\exists C>0$ such that $|f(x+t_{0})-f(t_0)|\le C|x|^{\alpha}$, but I do not know how to proceed with tackling the problem.

Comment: @ᴡᴏʀᴅs Thanks, I've edited that now.

Comment: I don't understand what is $(\lambda_n)$. Let $T = 2\pi$, Is it supposed to be an increasing sequence of integers ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, exactly; it's a sequence of positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your formula $\hat{f}(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_{n}\cos(\lambda_{n}t)$ is way off. In fact $\hat f(\pm\lambda_n)=a_n/2$ and $\hat f(j)=0$ if $j\ne\lambda_n$.

Note as well that assuming $f$ is $Lip_\alpha$ at one point implies $a_n=O(\lambda_n^{-\alpha})$ for $0<\alpha\le 1$, but that condition on the $a_n$ only implies that $f\in Lip_\alpha$ for $0<\alpha<1$. (For $\alpha=1$ it implies that $f$ is in the so-called Zygmund class.)

**First Half:**

We need to construct a few kernels. The construction is actually easier on the line, where we can use dilations; we'll use Poisson summation to get from the line back to the circle. (The reason I'm writing this out instead of just referring to some book is that people often construct the required kernels as linear combinations of Fejer kernels; I feel the construction below is much more transparent.)

Choose a Schwarz function $\psi$ with $$\hat\psi(1)=1$$  and $$supp(\hat\psi)\subset\left(\frac1q,q\right).$$  For $\lambda>0$ let $$\psi_\lambda(t)=\lambda\psi(\lambda t),$$so that $||\psi_\lambda||_1=||\psi||_1$ and $$\hat\psi_\lambda(\xi)=\hat\psi\left(\frac\xi\lambda\right);$$in particular $\hat\psi_\lambda(\lambda)=1$ and $\hat\psi_\lambda$ is supported in $(\lambda/q,\lambda q)$.

Now define a $2\pi$-periodic function $\phi_n$ by $$\phi_n(t)=\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}\psi_{\lambda_n}(t+2\pi j),$$so that $$||\phi_n||_{L^1(\Bbb T)}\le\||\psi_{\lambda_n}||_{L^1(\Bbb R)}=||\psi||_{L^1(\Bbb R)}$$and $$\hat\phi_n(k)=\widehat{\psi_{\lambda_n}}(k)\quad(k\in\Bbb Z).$$(There are a few $\pi$'s missing here; look up Poisson summmation and get this straight before you hand it in.) See **Details** below.

In particular $$\hat\phi_n(\lambda_n)=1$$and $$\hat\phi_n(k)=0\quad(k\notin(\lambda_n/q,\lambda_nq),$$so $\hat\phi_n(\lambda_j)=0$ if $j\ne n$.

Assume $t_0=0$ for convenience. Since $f$ has period $2\pi$ the definition of $\phi_n$ shows that we have $$a_n=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\phi_n(-t)\,dt=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\psi_{\lambda_n}(-t)\,dt
=\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t/\lambda_n)\psi(-t)\,dt.$$

Now since $\int\psi=0$ it follows that

$$a_n=
\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(t/\lambda_n)-f(0))\psi(-t)\,dt.$$

So $$|a_n|\le\lambda_n^{-\alpha}\frac C\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty|t|^\alpha|\psi(t)|\,dt=O(\lambda_n^{-\alpha}).$$

**Second Half:**

Now to show that that implies $f\in Lip_\alpha$, if $0<\alpha<1$: We have $$|f(s)-f(t)|\le c\sum\lambda_n^{-\alpha}|e^{i\lambda_ns}-e^{i\lambda_nt}|.$$Note that $$|e^{i\lambda s}-e^{i\lambda t}|\le 2$$and also $$|e^{i\lambda s}-e^{i\lambda t}|\le \lambda|s-t|.$$We use one estimate on some of the terms and the other on the other terms. Choose $N$ so $\lambda_N|s-t|\le 1$ and $\lambda_{N+1}|s-t|>1$. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda_n^{-\alpha}|e^{i\lambda_ns}-e^{i\lambda_nt}|
\le\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda_n^{1-\alpha}|s-t|
\le\lambda_N^{1-\alpha}|s-t|\sum_{k=-\infty}^0q^{k(1-\alpha)}
=c\lambda_N^{1-\alpha}|s-t|^{1-\alpha}|s-t|^\alpha\le c|s-t|^\alpha$$
(note we used $1-\alpha>0$ there, twice.)

On the other hand, since $\alpha>0$ we have $$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\lambda_n^{-\alpha}|e^{i\lambda_ns}-e^{i\lambda_nt}|
\le 2\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\lambda_n^{-\alpha}
\le 2\lambda_{N+1}^{-\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^{-k\alpha}
=c\lambda_{N+1}^{-\alpha}\le c|s-t|^\alpha.$$

**Details** The essence of the Possion Summation Formula is this:

**Proposition** Suppose $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$. Then the series $$g(t)
=\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}f(t+2\pi j)$$converges absolutely almost everywhere. We have $$||g||_{L^1(\Bbb T)}\le\frac1{2\pi}||f||_{L^1(\Bbb R};$$further, if $n\in\Bbb Z$ then $$\hat g(n)=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\hat f(n).$$

Proof: Monotone convergence, the translation invariance of Lebesgue measure and then MCT again show that $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}|f(t+2\pi j)|
=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}\int_{2\pi j}^{2\pi(j+1)}|f(t)|\,dt
=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(t)|\,dt.$$So the sum converges almost everywhere. If $n\in\Bbb Z$ then $e^{-int}$ has period $2\pi$; since the sum converges in $L^1$ this shows that $$\hat g(n)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)e^{-int}
=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-int}
=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}\hat f(n).$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but after the construction of the very first functions $\psi$ and $\psi_{\lambda}$ I fail to see how it follows that $\|\psi_{\lambda}\|_{L^{1}}=\|\psi\|_{L^{1}}$ )and moreover how $\hat{\psi}_{\lambda}(\xi)=\hat{\psi}(\xi/\lambda)$).

Comment: @user3482534 That's just "calculus" - a change of variable in the integral...

Comment: Okay, I see how it follows for the $L^{1}$ norm, but for the Fourier transform I get: $$\begin{aligned}
 \hat{\psi}_{\lambda}(\xi)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi x}\psi_{\lambda}(x)dx
 \\
 &=\lambda\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi x}\psi(\lambda x)dx
 \\
 &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi\frac{y}{\lambda}}\psi(y)dy\qquad\text{for }y=\lambda x
 \end{aligned}$$

Is the final integral equal to $\hat{\psi}(\xi/\lambda)$?

Comment: @user3482534 ??? What would the _definition_ of $\hat\psi(\xi/\lambda)$ be?

Comment: Oddly, I've never seen that in literature. But since $$\hat{\psi}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi x}\psi(x)dx$$ it does indeed follow that $$\hat{\psi}\left(\frac{\xi}{\lambda}\right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi \frac{\xi}{\lambda}} \psi(x)dx.$$

Comment: @user3482534 This is a very standard, very useful thing. It's one of the major reasons why the Fourier transform can be more convenient than Fourier series, the way the FT interacts with dilations. Have you read much literature on the FT, as opposed to Fourier series?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've had some education on the theory of distributions and harmonic analysis and oddly I'm only delving into the theory of Fourier series now during my break before I begin a formal course on it.

Comment: Well if you learned about Schwarz functions and tempered distriibutions, if the treatment was remotely like any treatment I can imagine, then you _have_ seen that identity before.

Comment: The first identity, certainly. Now, with regards to the inequality $\|\phi_{n}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{T})}\le\|\psi_{\lambda_{n}}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}}$; I don't intuitively see how $$\int_{\mathbb{T}}|\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(t+2\pi j)|dt\le\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\psi_{\lambda_{n}}|dt $$
For $\hat{\phi}_{n}(k)$ I assume this means the Fourier coefficients of $\phi_{n}$; then $$\hat{\phi}_{n}(k)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\phi_{n}(s)e^{-ins}\frac{ds}{2\pi}$$ and comparing the integrals for $\hat{\phi}_{n}(k)=\hat{\psi}_{\lambda_{n}}$ would give that $$\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(s+2\pi j)=\psi_{\lambda_{n}}$$.

Comment: @user3482534 Hint for that inequality: $\int_a^b f(t+c)\,dt=\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f$. No, comparing integrals does not give what you say...

Comment: @user3482534 General hint for that part: I suggested "look up Poisson summmation ". Have you figured out how that's really spellled and then looked it up??

Comment: Following that hint for that inequality yields $$\begin{aligned} \int_{\mathbb{T}}|\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(t+2\pi j)|dt &\le\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{\mathbb{T}}|\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(t+2\pi j)|dt \\ &=\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{2\pi j}^{2\pi+2\pi j}|\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(t)|dt \\ &=\int_{\mathbb{T}}|\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(t)|dt \end{aligned}$$ which is $\|\psi_{\lambda_{n}}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{T})}$ rather than $\|\psi_{\lambda_{n}}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}$, assuming that all of my calculations were correct.

Comment: For the second equality, I did indeed look up the Poisson summation formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula

Utilising equation 3 from there yields $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(s+2\pi j)e^{-ins}\frac{ds}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \hat{\psi}_{\lambda_{n}}\left(\frac{k}{2\pi}\right)e^{iks}\cdot e^{-ins}\frac{ds}{2\pi}$$

Comment: With regards to the first inequality, I notice that in Grafakos' book 'Classical Fourier Analysis' he *does* mention that the Poisson summation formula is a "useful result that connects Fourier analysis on the Torus with Fourier analysis on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$", although I don't necessarily see that upon inspection.

Comment: @user3482534 In fact $\sum_j\int_{2\pi j}^{2\pi(j+1)}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty$. Regarding Poisson summation: That formula you cite requires _hypotheses_ that do not hold here - the point to suggesting you look up Poisson summation is that the proof of that formula does what you asked about.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the proof. Again, it's that same trick which gives us $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi_{\lambda_{n}}(s)e^{-ins}\frac{ds}{2\pi}.$$ Since $\psi_{\lambda_{n}}$ was not assumed to be $2\pi$-periodic I would assume that the above is equal to $\hat{\psi}_{\lambda_{n}}(k)/2\pi$ which would probably be the "missing $\pi$'s" you referred to (which, subsequently, would also occur in the definition of $\hat{\phi}_{n}(\lambda_{n})$ and the support of $\hat{\phi}_{n}$).

Comment: @user3482534 See the **Details** added in latest edit. There $g$ _is_ periodic, and $\hat g(n)$ is the Fourier coefficient. Otoh $f$ is not periodic; $\hat f(n)$ is the Fourier transform.

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't quite been able to figure out the central idea of the argument: would you be able to explain to me in a clear cut way why the construction of $\phi_{n}$ means that we can write $a_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\phi_{n}(-t)dt$?

Also, why exactly can we write $|f(s)-f(t)|\le C\sum\lambda_{n}^{-\alpha}|e^{i\lambda_{n}s}-e^{i\lambda_{n}t}|$? I assume it has to do with necessary (possibly Hölder) conditions being satisfied for convergence of the Fourier series...

Comment: @user3482534 First question: This is clear from the definition of $\hat f(n)$, since $\phi_n$ is a trigonometric polynomial with $\hat\phi_n(n)=1$. Second question: This is immediate from the triangle inequality, because at that point we've shown that $|a_n|\le c\lambda_n^{-a}$.